# Did Young Justice purposely reference The Bourne series?

Tags: reference, young-justice, bourne-series

In Young Justice S01E16 aka Failsafe, during the simulation when they send Superhero and soldiers from  Hall of Justice to Mount Justice, when Superboy sent the first soldier in transportation, scanner said his name is Jason Bourne.

Did Young Justice purposely refereed [The Bourne Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_%28film_series%29)? But why was this random reference? Is it some part of deal or just coincident?

Comment: As a note,  DC rarely references other franchises. Marvel does quite often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The computer says `Private Jason Bard USMC` The time code in the episode is 11:55 seconds (or there about). - http://watchcartoonsonline.eu/watch/young-justice-season-1-episode-16-failsafe/

**Jason Bard is actually a recurring character in the DC universe dating back to the 1960s, so he isn't a reference to Jason Bourne.**

> Jason Bard appears in the Young Justice episode "Failsafe", voiced by Jeff Bennett. He is portrayed as a young private in the U.S. Marine Corps rather than a detective. He served under General Wade Eiling at the time when Earth was attacked by an alien armada that took out the Justice League and all other superheroes that were fighting them. The events of the episode turned out to be a mental training overseen by Martian Manhunter. According to Greg Weisman, Jason Bard was an old friend of Martian Manhunter and had previously injured his leg during his service in the U.S. Marine Corps. - [Wikipedia/Jason Bard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Bard)

Comment: Jack was quick.